Unable to stop connect to Kafka broker after several attempts
I have a simple Kafka project bootstrapped by spring-kafka.
I encountered a problem that I cannot control how to stop connecting to Kafka broker after several attempts. Does anyone know where should I configure to make sure the Kafka client would not connect to Kafka broker anymore if certain criteria is fulfilled.
Below is the log.
2024-05-22T16:04:10.009+08:00  WARN 47159 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker coherent-penguin-12917-us1-kafka.upstash.io:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-05-22T16:04:41.341+08:00  INFO 47159 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.

I have tried delivery.timeout.ms and connections.max.idle and set it to 30 seconds.

With configurations you can mostly add a bigger delay in which the messages will show in the logs by using a combination of these configs for the producer: retries, retry.backoff.ms, delivery.timeout.ms, reconnect.backoff.ms. I wouldn't recommend stopping the application of retrying if it is suppose to send something to kafka and it is not being able to, something is wrong. However if you still want to do this, one possibility is to use a library like Resilience4J and create a circuit breaker for the kafka producer configuration.
